# Search across multiple data models in Django

Tags: python, django

My search on the site is implemented as follows:

**views.py:**

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app/search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'q' in self.request.GET and self.request.GET['q']:
            query = self.request.GET['q']
            object_list = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(text__icontains=query))
            return object_list
        else:
            return None
```

**urls.py:**

```
path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

As you can see this is true only for one model, but I also need to do a search on all the necessary models and combine the result.

How is it better to implement in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to break load by using a flag in search field like below :

```
querystring = request.GET.get('q', '')
key_search = request.GET.get('key_search')
```

this is the front-end part :

```
$('#searched-item').on('input change', function() {
    var key_search = document.getElementsByName('key-search')[0].value;
    var q = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/autocomplete/",
            data: {
                'q': q,
                'key_search': key_search
                },
            success: function (data) {
            }
      });
});
```

then fetching data like this (for example if you have post then use 'p' as a flag and if you have Question model then use 'q'):

```
articles = []
questions = []
if key_search == "p":
    pages = list(
        Post.objects.filter(Q(page_name__icontains=querystring), 
        is_reported=False, post_status="TA"))
elif key_search == "q":
    posts = list(
         Question.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=querystring) | Q(
         summary__icontains=querystring), status='P'))
```

I hope this helps.